# Crystal report - Watermark in subreport

Tags: crystal-reports, watermark, subreport

I have a crystal report for an application form, which I have done by using an image as a water mark in the page header, and then have some fields to be overlayed in the details section by having the page header set to `Underlay Following sections`.

That all works nicely, but now I want to print another report with this: basically a cover letter which is the primary data set; which then calls my application form report as a sub report. However because subreports don't have page headers, I can't get the watermark and the fields to overlay with each other regardless of what `keep togethor` or `underlay following sections` I select on groupings.

Has anyone tried to do this before, and has been able to do it at all? I can't find anything.

OR has anyone created a watermark report, that then supresses the watermark for a subreport (basically reversing the logic above).

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you tried making a top grouping for something that is the same for every record, checking Repeat Group Heading On Each Page in the group options, and then underlying it in the section options?

Comment: This might sound like a silly hack, but I'm serious. There are certain things you have to "hack" to get around in Crystal Reports from time to time.

Comment: that's exactly what i'd suggest. page header is no go... report header is no good as wont repeat for multiple pages... group header will do what you want

Comment: Thank you @Ally and Lee for that, works like a dream.

Comment: Would @Ally please enter the comment as an answer instead so it can be marked as correct and upvoted?

Answer (score 1):

If making a page header to underlay won't work, here's another option.

Make a top grouping that is the same for every record (e.g. the company the grand total of the report is for.) In Group Options, check the box for "Repeat Group Heading On Each Page." In Section Options, check "Underlay Following Sections."

Now, whatever you put in that header will be repeated on every page and everything else will go over it.